# Inserting image in pdf with pdfkit nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I´d really appreciate help with this.
I am trying to add an image to a pdf I´m generating with PDFKIT. The image I´m trying to display comes from 'profilepicture.picture' which is a URL. I cannot pass that parameter directly to doc.image() because it only reads locally saved pictures.

PDFKIT documentation says
"Adding images to PDFKit documents is an easy task. Just pass an image path, buffer, or data uri with base64 encoded data to the image method along with some optional arguments. PDFKit supports the JPEG and PNG formats. "

So I have tried AXIOS and other ways to swith the image to base64, but still when trying to display the image as base64 is still not working... If I add an image I have locally then it works, but not with base64 or url from profilepicture.picture. The URL is ('https://ibookinfo.s3.amazonaws.com/ibookprofilepicture1694446561681.png'). I dont know what else to do. Please help. This is my code.

```
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit';
import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';
import fs from 'fs'
import axios from 'axios'


function createPDFInvoice(invoice, shipping, secondTotal, infofacturacion, profilepicture,         randomPart, agregarnota, callback) {
let doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4", margin: 50 });

generateHeader(doc, infofacturacion, profilepicture);
generateCustomerInformation(doc, invoice, shipping, secondTotal, randomPart);
generateInvoiceTable(doc, invoice, secondTotal);
generateFooter(doc, agregarnota, infofacturacion);

const pdfPath = `invoice_${Date.now()}.pdf`;
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(pdfPath);
    doc.end();

doc.pipe(stream);

stream.on('finish', () => {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(null, pdfPath); // Notify that the PDF creation is complete
        } else {
            console.error('Callback is not a function');
        }
    });
stream.on('error', (err) => {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(err); // Handle any errors during PDF creation
        } else {
            console.error('Callback is not a function');
        }
    });
}
```

```
async function convertImageToBase64(picture) {
  try {
      const imageResponse = await axios.get(picture, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
      const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(imageResponse.data);
      return imageBuffer.toString('base64');
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching image from URL:', error);
      return null; 
  }
}
```

```
async function generateHeader(doc, infofacturacion, profilepicture) {
    const base64Image = await convertImageToBase64(profilepicture.picture);

doc.fillColor('#444444')
        .image(`data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}`, 50, 45, { width: 50 })
        .fontSize(15)
        .text(`${infofacturacion.nombreempresa}`, 200, 60, { align: 'right' })
        .fontSize(10)
        .text(` ${infofacturacion.tipodenegocio}`, 200, 85, { align: 'right' })
        .text(`Cédula Jurídica:  ${infofacturacion.cedulajuridica}`, 200, 98, { align: 'right' })
        .text(` ${infofacturacion.nombreencargado}`, 200, 111, { align: 'right' })
        .text(`${infofacturacion.correoempresa} /  ${infofacturacion.telefonoempresa}`, 200, 124, {   align: 'right' })
        .text(`${infofacturacion.direccionempresa}, ${infofacturacion.paisempresa}`, 200, 137, { align: 'right' })
        .moveDown();
        }
```

Comment: Try to check if the image URL is accessible and returns a valid image.(By using Postman to verify that the image is accessible)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to fetch the image and then convert to array buffer and use that way.

```js
const response = await fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_Things#/media/File:Stranger_Things_logo.png");


const strangerThingsLogo = await response.arrayBuffer();


// then later in your create pdf function 

pdf.image(strangerThingsLogo, 16, 8, { height: 32 });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is true:

```
// Scale proprotionally to the specified width
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 0, 15, {width: 300})
   .text('Proportional to width', 0, 0);

// Fit the image within the dimensions
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 320, 15, {fit: [100, 100]})
   .rect(320, 15, 100, 100)
   .stroke()
   .text('Fit', 320, 0);

// Stretch the image
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 320, 145, {width: 200, height: 100})
   .text('Stretch', 320, 130);

// Scale the image
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 320, 280, {scale: 0.25})
   .text('Scale', 320, 265);

// Fit the image in the dimensions, and center it both horizontally and vertically
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 430, 15, {fit: [100, 100], align: 'center', valign: 'center'})
   .rect(430, 15, 100, 100).stroke()
   .text('Centered', 430, 0);
```